# Why am I getting records for BETWEEN condition with the same date in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I mistakenly typed the same date in this query to get orders placed on Jan 1st.

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders
WHERE  order_date BETWEEN To_date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
                          To_date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

However it worked well with my requirement and retrieved records for the date.

But now I am curious to know how and why this is working? Because dates default to having a time value of 00:00:00, so both dates here should be exactly the same moment of time , so theoretically it should return nothing with `BETWEEN` condition for any query.

Can someone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: If your `order_date` stores `date` values, this behavior is expected: any date is BETWEEN itself and itself, since there is likely no time comparison involved at all, and all these dates have exactly 0 time if cast to timestamp/timestamptz.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive of both range values, so this makes sense. And if it is only a date type, there is no time component.

Comment: Thanks @STerliakov and dfundako. I understood it now

Comment: If you want all orders on `2024-01-01` regardless of time, you could use `order_date::date = '2024-01-01'`

Comment: `x between a and b` is same as `x >= a and x <= b`.

Answer (score 0):

Dates of '2024-01-01' are equivalent to '2024-01-01 00:00:00' and

if `order_date` is `2024-01-01` then it's

```
BETWEEN To_date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
        To_date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

so the result is accurate. If `order_date` is on `2024-01-01` and also has a non-0 time component, then it will not end up being in the interval.